# Create a custom Drawable from a Path

Tags: android, canvas, drawable

I try to make a custom Drawable which makes a Drawable from a Path. I know this can be done using a ShapeDrawable but I want to draw the same path more often on the same Drawable (but shifted on the y-axis) and of course learn how to implement a custom Drawable.

My code is listed below, unfortunately the activity does not display anything.

This is my custom Drawable class:

```
public class TestDrawable extends Drawable {

Path path;
Paint strokePaint;

public TestDrawable(Path path){
    this.path = path;
    strokePaint = new Paint();
    strokePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint);
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int i) {

}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
}
}
```

This is my main activity for testing:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView testImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testImage);
    Path path = CardBuilder.getPath();
    Drawable d = new TestDrawable(path);
    testImage.setImageDrawable(d);
}
}
```

The Path is valid (tested with a ShapeDrawable before).
What did I miss to do?

Additional Question:
How can I make my Drawable scale to fit the measures of my ImageView I use later on to display the Drawable?

Comment: override getIntrinsicWidth/Height to return your Path bounds width/height